# How to develop Joomla 1.5 componenets?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

How can I start developing a component for the Joomla 1.5 framework? Does anyone know of a good tutorial, or has a good reference?

I have read the tutorial on the wiki and I didn't understand it well, so if you could point me to another one, that would be great.

I know that ideally I should work with Joomla 2.5 or 3.0 but I am being asked to develop this for an existing website, I can't decide which version to work on.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but why on earth you want to learn developing for the Joomla! 1.5 which is as we speak no longer supported. Take a look at the 2.5 & 3.0 series.

Comment: I Strongly agree. It is pointless starting to develop for Joomla 1.5 as it's not supported anymore. Most support I would have thought is provided on here and even then, some people try persuading the OP to upgrade. You should really look into development for 2.5 / 3.x as standards of coding have were changed and will basically stay as is.

Comment: Try and find a copy of Joe LeBlanc's book which is a beginning joomla development book for 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think the official tutorials in Joomla! Documentation really do cut it. Give it a try - http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development

Comment: I did read it, but I couldn't understand it all to well unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> *I can't decide which version to work on*

I personally would use Joomla 2.5 as it's the long term lease of the Joomla series and has much more documentation and support. Joomla 3.0 is the short term release, therefore is a beta version of 3.5 so to speak.

Seeing as you are using Joomla 1.5 at the moment, you could always upgrade to Joomla 2.5 using [JUpgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658) which is a free extension. Note that this won't upgrade 3rd party extensions, so you will need to install the Joomla 2.5 compatible versions for each one (providing there is one).

To get you started on a Joomla 2.5 component, have a look at the [Joomla 2.5 MVC Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction). This also provides zip files of a HelloWorld component for you to download at various stages.

You might also be interested in a [Component Generator](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/webbased-tools/7627).

Hope this helps.